# Image Resizing before uploading

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm uploading images from my node application to cloudinary using buffer. What I want to do is to resize those images and upload them after that to cloudinary.

```
// upload image on cloudinary
        cloudinary.v2.uploader
            .upload_stream({ resource_type: 'image' }, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return;
                }
                // set this as a product_img in req.body
                images.push(result.secure_url);
                // if images length equal to files length
                // set images on body
                if (req.files.length === images.length) {
                    req.body.images = images;
                    next();
                }
            })
            .end(file.buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of 3rd party libraries in order to resize the image before uploading.
Note that when using Cloudinary, it would be better to upload the original image and only then deliver the image with new dimensions.

Best,
--Yakir